# Select certain columns from one table and a count from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have checked out a number of answers to similar questions but still can't quite get it right.

I have two tables, `Stock-Details` and `Goods-In`. Both tables have an ID Primary Key. The column value that matches them is `PrimarySKU` (in `Stock-Details` and `SKU` (in `Goods-In`).

So, my first query might be:

```
"SELECT `id`,`Nominal`,`OnOrder`,`PrimarySKU` FROM `Stock-Details`
    WHERE 'Nominal` < '10'"
```

And my second query would be:

```
"SELECT COUNT FROM `Goods-In`
    WHERE `UsedByOrderNumber`=''
    AND `SKU`= `PrimarySKU` (From My First Table.)"
```

How can I combine these into a single fast query that will give me all the columns in `Stock-Details` and the count of the rows in `Goods-In` where the `UsedByOrderNumber` is empty or used or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting a count by SKU where the UsedByOrderNumber is null in a subquery, then join that to your Stock-Details table:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.nominal,
    t1.onorder,
    t1.primarySku
    t2.recordcount

FROM
    stock-details t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                SKU, 
                count(*) as recordcount 
            FROM Goods-In 
            WHERE UsedByOrderNumber IS NULL 
            GROUP BY SKU
        ) t2 ON
    t1.primarySku = t2.SKU
WHERE   
    t1.Nominal < 10
```

Comment: OK this worked somewhat.. thank you, but it only returns rows where a count value is found... ie where the count is greater than 0.. i need the query to return all rows from `stock-details` even if there is no matching SKU in the `Goods-In` table and return a count of 0.

Comment: The only restriction in this query on the `stock-details` table is in the `WHERE` clause at the bottom. Other than that, every single record in `stock-details` will show up.

Comment: I am only getting 589 rows being returned when there are 1899 total rows in `stock-details`.  `RecordCount` is only 1 or more.. there are no 0s where there is either no matching SKU in the `goods-in` table at all, or there are are, but the `UsedByOrderNumber` is no longer null - ie that stock item has been used.

Comment: How many records do you get when you run `SELECT count(*) from stock-details WHERE t1.Nominal < 10;`?

Comment: to clarify - i'm not using the t1.Nominal < 10  clause, and I get 1899 results

Comment: My apologies. I'm having one of those days and I've been completely ignoring the obvious. Change the query in my answer to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`... I thought it was already. That will probably give you the results you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect - All rows returned and Record Count Returns Null if there is no count found. I don't suppose there is anyway to make that a 0?

Comment: Sure, you could use `COALESCE(t2.recordcount, 0) as recordcount`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that function. Just read up on it. Where in the query do you use that?

Comment: ^ @Davros: in your outer set of columns, swap `t2.recordcount` to the line JNevill has suggested in the above comment.